# How to setup a task.json used by all folders (VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want to set every time I start a project (Folder) a new `./.vscode/task.json`.
Could this file be global as `keybindings.json`?
Or at least can I create my own template that would show up when I *Configure Task Runner*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not possible at the moment.
There is an open issue at this purpose: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2775

Comment: Is this still the case?